# How to make progress bar location to be synchronous when maximizing the windows form?

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar, docking

I tried docking but it works in some pre defined positions. I want to place it in a small area at the bottom of the form and keep its relative position when maximizing the form.

Comment: Anchor it, either Left/Bottom or Right/Bottom, depending on its position. *location* and *synchronous* don't really go well together. You also have the ProgressBar of a StatusStrip, in case your design allows it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold the progressor position steady with the anchor. `Anchor = Bottom, Left` means that my distance from the bottom and left is the same in all sizes of Windows.

*If I am now 10px from the left, I will be 10px away from the resize, and so bottom*

Answer (score 0):

you can put the progress bar inside a panel then dock the panel on bottom part.
Check this out;

actual size
[image]

Maximized

[image]

But please take a note to place the progress bar on the upper left corner inside the panel